# implementing a static og image in Gatsby

Tags: gatsby

I'm new in Gatsby and can't find a solution for this:
I deployed a website which is just a "coming soon" landing page for now.
I took a screenshot which i want to use as og-image for everything...
It's now sitting in src/images but:

- if i don't import it anywhere, it's not going to be available in the public folder after build
- if i import it, it's in the static folder but with a unique hash, so i'm not able to set the meta-tag correctly in the SEO file using Helmet.

  ```
  return (
    <Helmet
      htmlAttributes={{
        lang,
      }}
      title={title}
      titleTemplate={`%s | ${site.siteMetadata.title}`}
      meta={[
        {
          name: `description`,
          content: metaDescription,
        },
        {
          property: `og:title`,
          content: title,
        },
        {
          property: `og:description`,
          content: metaDescription,
        },
        {
          property: `og:image`,
          content: 'https://example.com/{how to get to the url of my image???}',
        },
        {
          property: `og:type`,
          content: `website`,
        },
        {
          name: `twitter:card`,
          content: `summary`,
        },
        {
          name: `twitter:creator`,
          content: site.siteMetadata.author,
        },
        {
          name: `twitter:title`,
          content: title,
        },
        {
          name: `twitter:description`,
          content: metaDescription,
        },
      ].concat(meta)}
    />
  )
  ```

  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hit the nail, the way to achieve what you want is to add it in your `/static` folder since you are not importing it as a component so the way to make the image available is this.

The `URL` of the image is the name of the image itself, with the same internal folder structure. As you can see in [Gatsby documentation about static folder](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-folder/#adding-assets-outside-of-the-module-system):

> You can create a folder named static at the root of your project.
> Every file you put into that folder will be copied into the public
> folder. E.g. if you add a file named `sun.jpg` to the static folder,
> it’ll be copied to `public/sun.jpg`

In the previous case, the `sun.jpg` must be just one level inside `/static`. If you add another level, like `/images/sun.jpg`, your public `URL` will be `https://example.com/images/sun.jpg`.

So, in your case:

```
  {
    property: `og:image`,
    content: 'https://example.com/path_to_your_static_image.extension',
  },
```

*Note: keep in mind that being a public `URL`, it won't work until you deploy your app and the image remain public*

Comment: Thank you so much, this opens a whole range of possibilities :)